# using awk insdie xargs construct

Tags: bash, awk, xargs

using awk in xargs construct: getting different output when am tyring to pull in awk inside xargs - -

step1

```
 ~/waste/dgx-users2.log | head -n2
node1
node2
```

step2

```
cat ~/waste/dgx-users2.log | head -n2 | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'echo $1 && kubectl get pods --field-selector=spec.nodeName=$1,status.phase=Running --all-namespaces --no-headers' --

node1
node2
test-s test-s-pod 3/3   Running   0     6d1h
dummy-s test-s-pod 1/1 Running 0 5d9h
```

but i only want test-s in $1 to be listed so filter below

```
cat ~/waste/dgx-users2.log | head -n2 | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'echo $1 && kubectl get pods --field-selector=spec.nodeName=$1,status.phase=Running --all-namespaces --no-headers' -- | awk '$1 ~ /test-*/ && /Running/ {print}'
test-s test-pod                       3/3   Running   0     6d
```

Above is all good but is there a way I can pull the awk inside xargs — ? I tried below but its missing the last output line that shows in my expected output.

```
cat ~/waste/dgx-users2.log | head -n2 | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'echo $1 && kubectl get pods --field-selector=spec.nodeName=$1,status.phase=Running --all-namespaces --no-headers | awk "$1 ~ /test-*/ && /Running/ {print}"' --
node1
node2
```

Am not getting the same output.. so need to adjust some syntax, i guess..
my expected output should be.

my goal is to print that node info along with output such that i know on what node that pod is running like below node1 has nothing and node2 has a pod it.

```
node1
node2
test-s test-pod                       3/3   Running   0     6d
```

Comment: Can you simplify this a bit so we don't need your log file to run it and get your expected output? For example, you could write a function `gen_log() { cat <<'EOF'`, have a few lines of log, then `EOF`; and then `gen_log | xargs -l1 ...`

Comment: The obvious problem is that when you change from `awk '$1 ...` to `awk "$1...`, more escaping is needed to stop the `$1` from being expanded by a shell before awk sees it. That is, change `"$1` to `"\$1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `$1` in the awk expression is being parsed in a double-quoted context by the internal copy of `sh`, it needs to be escaped. That is:

```
head -n2 <~/waste/dgx-users2.log | xargs -l1 -- sh -c '
    echo "$1" &&
    kubectl get pods --field-selector=spec.nodeName="$1",status.phase=Running \
                     --all-namespaces --no-headers |
    awk "\$1 ~ /test-*/ && /Running/ {print}"
  ' --
```

Comment: btw: do you think am doing it the right way? is there a better solution to my approach?

Comment: I'd iterate over your file (or the relevant subset) using a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop, instead of using `xargs` at all. That said, if you go that route, be careful of the issue described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).